# How to use zf1 validators to validate model in service?

Tags: validation, zend-framework, service

I have injected a service layer in Zend Framework 1 project. The project also has REST API for android and other devices. My project layout looks like this

```
Application 
 modules
      default
         controller
             CustomerController.php [for web]
      api
         controllers
              CustomerController.php [for android device]
 services
   CustomerService.php
```

While CustomerService.php class handles all customer creation logic and is consumed by CustomerController.php in both api and default module. Its easy to validate the values submitted by users in web using form. How can I validate the values submitted by users in service so that there is no code repetition in both front and api controllers for validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same form class to validate your data in the API Controller and in the web Controller :

In your web controller, you probably have something like:

```
$form = new CustomerForm();
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        // persist your Customer here, then redirect
    }
}
$this->view->form = $form;
```

In your API controller, use your form in the same way. You just have to send back the form errors if validation has failed.

```
$form = new CustomerForm();
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        // Validation passed.

        // TODO: persist your Customer here, then send back the Customer data (as JSON / XML).

        return;

    } else {
        // Validation failed. Send back form error messages and set HTTP response code to 400 (bad request)
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(400);
        $errors = $this->form->getMessages();

        // TODO: send your errors here (as JSON or XML)
    }
}
```